# How to know when an exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, thrift

I'm working with the Apache Thrift tool and i'm throwing some Exceptions from the server side to the client side.

The only problem is that when the client is calling a method returning a boolean Thrift is ignoring the Exception and the server is sending back the value of the boolean:

[Here is the issue opened](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1474)

So i was wondering if it's possible after calling the method to check if an exception has been thrown since my try/catch block is not doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my problem I used something not very clean but it does the trick:
I defined a new struct in Thrift acting like a wrapper for the boolean value:

```
struct thriftBool{1: bool success = false,}
```

Now my client receives all the exception and instead of doing

```
if(client.myMethod())
```

I'm doing:

```
if(client.myMethod().success)
```

Edit: It seems that the 0.9 version of Thrift fixes the issue.

Comment: Do you know how the 0.9 version fixes this issue?

Comment: Don't know, just I have been doing some tests one year after I opened my ticket and the issue seemed solved. After I have kept the wrapper so I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could use AOP.  Just add an exception handling pointcut.